# Adding tagged / dynamic pages in sitemap

Tags: sitemap, web-crawlers, xml-sitemap, dynamic

I've got a blog that's been running for about a year, with about 200 posts, and there should be about 220 pages to index (additional pages for about / contact etc).

When I go to crawl the site I get 1900 pages because of all the pages that are related to tags I've used in my posts; 70% of these pages only contain one blog post.

When submitting my site map to Google should I exclude all pages with /tagged/ in the URL so I'll only be submitting unique pages, or should I submit the full site map?

Answer (score 1):

You should filter "/tagged/" so you don't get duplicate content.  The 200 posts are your most important content.  However, if you do want to add all 1900 then you should add `<priority>0.4</priority>` in your sitemap to all of the pages with with "/tagged/" and set the core 200 pages to 0.8; with the homepage at 1.0.